# How to handle unAuthorized user and redirect it to 403 page in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, axios

If the user is not logged in and he tries to directly access the app, then the backend API will give the 403 error, How to catch this error and then redirect the user to a 403 page and give him option to login .

I am using axios to fetch data from backend API.
React-router for routing, Redux for state-management
And we are doing Session-based Authentication.

Comment: What are you using for Authentication purposes, JWT or Passport, etc.?

Comment: Session based Authentication

Comment: The session wouldn't work. Try your hand with JWT. It's simple and one of the best.

Comment: Yes I know about the perks , but as a team we have gone with session based Authentication, It would be good if you can help in this scenario

Comment: Try @dahan raz's solution. It seems workable in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Just Do

```
axios.get(example)
    .then((response) => {
        // Success
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // Error
        switch (error.response.status) {
            case 403:
                //handle route to the page
            default:
                break
         }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @dahan for the quick reply.

Can you tell what I can use in case to handle the routes.

I tried this 
props.history.push("/homepage");

but it gave me an error

Comment: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: history is undefined.
create history.js file and write below code

import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory();

in your route file pass history as props

import history from './history';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

<Router history={history}>

Comment: Thanks guys, 

I include {withRouter} and wrapped my component with it and it worked. 
However will check the difference between your solution and the solution I used.

But I need to include this switch statement in every API Call, is there any generic method to catch 403 error for all API's call

Comment: I think  interceptor should do it. check - https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors

Comment: Try to implement the protected route.

Comment: Yes interceptors to catch exceptions globally.

Comment: Ok thanks guys , will check the interceptor link that you shared.

Answer (score 2):

Interceptor is a way to handle request-response globally in Axios. [Read More](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors)

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(response => response, error => {
   if (error.response.status === 403 ){
      // redirect to 403 page
      window.location = '/403'
   }
});
```